# Select2 li - aria-selected=true is not read as selected by screen reader

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, wai-aria, jquery-select2-4

I am currently using select2.js version 4.0 and having this issue where screen reader (NVDA) won't read the selected option, even aria-selected="true" is added correctly to the current selected li. And when I go the unselected options, it read as example, "German not selected" which is correct. I tried using the version 4.1 as well but still having the same problem. I was wondering if there's an issue with aria-selected="true" in select2.js? can't really find a stated issue for this. Thanks for the help.

Here's my select option after select2 is applied,

[image]

And here's the view when opened

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's how NVDA works.  Each screen reader (NVDA, JAWS, Voiceover, Talkback, Narrator, etc) will choose how to announce aria attributes.  In this case, for `aria-selected`, you get different results for `aria-selected` depending on the `role` of the element **and** you get different results in different browsers.  You can try to code around this by having your own hidden text that the screen reader reads but in general it's just best to let the screen reader decide how an attribute will be read.

Here's how convoluted `aria-selected` is just for Firefox and Chrome (let alone Edge, Safari, or IE).  And this is just with NVDA.  I'm sure the results will be difference for JAWS, Voiceover, etc.

### Firefox

`role="tab"`

- defaut is *"selected"* whether you have the `aria-selected` attribute or not
- only get [silence, meaning "not selected"] when `aria-selected=false`

`role="option"`

- defaut is *"not selected"* whether you have the `aria-selected` attribute or not
- only get [silence, meaning "selected"] when `aria-selected=true`

`role="gridcell"`

- defaut is *"not selected"* whether you have the `aria-selected` attribute or not
- only get *"selected"* when `aria-selected=true`

`role="row"` (same behavior as option)

- defaut is *"not selected"* whether you have the `aria-selected` attribute or not
- only get [silence, meaning "selected"] when `aria-selected=true`

### Chrome

`role="tab"` (different than firefox)

- defaut is [silence, meaning "not selected"] whether you have the `aria-selected` attribute or not
- only get "selected" when `aria-selected=true`

`role="option"` (same behavior as firefox)

- defaut is *"not selected"* whether you have the `aria-selected` attribute or not
- only get [silence, meaning "selected"] when `aria-selected=true`

`role="gridcell"` (different than firefox)

- doesn't work at all

`role="row"` (different than firefox)

- defaut is [silence, meaning "selected"] whether you have the `aria-selected` attribute or not
- only get "not selected" when `aria-selected=false`